# Subscribe to newsletter, mailchimp

Tags: mailchimp

Is it possible to have single button on website that leads user to MailChimp subscribe form that is not physically on that website? Like for example MailChimp "Thank you" page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to MailChimp Dashboard.
2. Select the list that you want to setup the subscriber form.
3. Go to 'Signup forms'
4. Select 'General forms'
5. Build the form and copy 'Signup form URL'

   Use the URL in your website, which leads anyone to the subscription form of your MailChimp list.