# Mailchimp newsletter subscribe not working in html

Tags: html, mailchimp

I put in the subscribe form on my website by performing as the link here "[Subscribe to newsletter, mailchimp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806152/subscribe-to-newsletter-mailchimp)" but when I try and put in an email to subscribe, it just stuck and didn't submit the email to the list in MailChimp.

Here's my code in html.

```html
<form id="mc-form" method="post" action="{the mail chimp signup form url}">
                  <div class="subscribe-form">
                          <input name="email" id="mc-email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="text-input">
                          <button class="submit-btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
                  </div>
        <label for="mc-email" class="mc-label"></label>
         </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<button class="submit-btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

to

```
<input class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: Hi, Tq for the response. I change the code as per your code but still, it was stuck at the same place.

Comment: Does anything happen when you press submit ? Are you sure you've replace the action attribute value with the actual URL ? obvious i know but need to check that first.